# Contents of file echoed to screen and not executed

Tags: php, include, mediawiki

I've been getting this error on my MediaWiki installation, but I'm not sure it's too localized to MediaWiki.

When including (or requiring, or using other methods) a file in a PHP script, I'm getting this:

```
class aClass() { }                               //Contents of file
Fatal error: Class 'aClass' not found in /path/path/file.php on line 9
```

`aClass` is just a test, and as you can see, it's not being loaded.

`aClass` is defined in the file I'm including. (This file is the one being echoed.) This file contains just the `class aClass() { }` statement, nothing else.

This is the file that does the requiring:

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/';

$wgAutoloadClasses['RatingData'] = $dir . 'RatingDataClass.php';
//MediaWiki class-loading statement

include $dir . 'RatingDataClass.php'; 
//simple include still fails

new aClass();
```

Without the `new aClass();`, the page loads fine, no errors or anythin abnormal echoed.

Comment: Where is the class aClass defined?

Comment: @andrewsi good point, I've made it clearer.

Comment: So the contents of the file is just the single line `class aClass() { }` ? If not, could you add the full text of that file, too?

Comment: yes, and I've updated the q as well.

Comment: And I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in your class file to tell PHP that it's to be processed, so it's being treated as HTML; try wrapping it in `<?php` tags:

```
<?php

class aClass() { }

?>
```

Comment: Just about to answer my own question, I just found that out a second ago as well. (I'm an idiot!) Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's one of those things that having someone else take a look at helps no end.